# When line tangent to the curve is the y axis (x=0), why must the point have the following conditions? "Denominator must = 0" & "Numerator NOT = 0"

Tags: calculus, curves, implicit-differentiation

I'm thrown off by the statement of this point.

Why in order to have a slope equaling the y axis, do we need:
The denominator of the derivative must equal 0.
The numerator of the derivative must not equal 0.

[image]

Comment: You want the limit of the derivative to be $\infty$, and hence a sufficient condition is the one stated in 3-4. It could also be that the limit is $\infty$ when both the numerator and denominator tend to $0$.

Comment: If we want the slope to tend to 0, shouldn't we accept numerator, 2(x-1) = 0? Why does KA state that it should NOT be zero...?

As for the denominator of the slope when it is zero, would be undefined, not infinity? Can you help me identify my knowledge gap here, please

Comment: The tangent is the $y$-axis right? Then what is its slope? $0$ or $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, the tangent will be infinity. Which is the same as undefined, right?

Comment: Yes, when the numerator does not tend to $0$ and the denominator goes to $0$, the slope goes to infinity, and this is what you want.

Comment: $y=\frac43$ is actually the $y$-coordinate of two points where one of the tangent is vertical: at $x\sim -2.2;\;x \sim 4.2$